# Vuetify tooltip in data table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add some tool tip in a vuetify datatable , but nothing happen.

this is the template that I need to use a tool tip

```
<template v-slot:item.state="{ item }">
   <div :class="lights(item)"></div>
</template>
```

and I use it like this

```
<v-tooltip left>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
         <template v-slot:item.state="{ item }">
           <div :class="lights(item)"></div>
         </template>
      </template>
   <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

and I have also an modal who need a tool tip but it have a v-slot activatior too :

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ toggle }">
   <v-tooltip bottom>
       <template v-slot:activator="{ on }" >
            <v-icon :color="color" v-on="on" v-on="toggle">mdi-power</v-icon>
        </template>
         <span>Tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

How can I do ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are close. The structure is a bit off and you're missing a key feature.

Refactor to the following structure:

```html
<template v-slot:item.state="{ item }">
  <v-tooltip left>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <div :class="lights(item)" v-on="on"></div>
    </template>
    <span>Tooltip: {{ item.yourKeyHere }}</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

You need to activate the hover mechanism via `on` so in the `div[class="lights(item)"]` template of the row `td` you need to set `v-on="on"`.

Below is a working example modified from the [Vuetify docs v-data-table example for customizing default rows](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#customizing-default-rows) ([alt](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#customizing-default-rows))

*Edit: Add nested components (dialog with a tooltip) using same default activator template syntax. (Click on the 'Fat' value in a row, then hover over dialog text to display tooltip)*

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.calories="{ item }">
        <v-tooltip left>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-chip dark v-on="on">{{ item.calories }}</v-chip>
           </template>
           <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
         </v-tooltip>
      </template>
      <!-- Edit to show independant nested activators -->
      <template v-slot:item.fat="{ item }">
        <v-dialog width="16rem">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <td v-on="on" style="cursor: pointer">{{ item.fat }}</td>
           </template>
           <v-card>
             <v-tooltip top color="primary">
               <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
             <v-card-title class="d-flex justify-center" v-on="on">{{ item.name }}</v-card-title>
               </template>
               <span>Fat: {{ item.fat }}</span>
             </v-tooltip>
          </v-card>
         </v-dialog>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it works for modals who have same on activator ?

Comment: @TheDevGuy  Activators are scoped, if that's what you mean. So you could have one `td` show a tooltip and another `td` in the same row display a dialog using the same boilerplate template.

Comment: I add the code in my first post because I don't understand what you mean sorry

Comment: I wondering how can I put 2 v-on="first" and v-on='second' on one line ?

Comment: @TheDevGuy Edited to show what I think you  mean -- nested components with independant activators.

Comment: Not Exaclty what i mean, I edit my post to show you my code,

Comment: I need at same time a tooltip and can open the modal

Comment: @TheDevGuy I'd question the need for this as the tooltip could be hidden by the modal or it's overlay. Unless you mean hover vs click activators. If that's the case then I would use `v-model` and `@handlers` since the activator is essentially short-hand for that.

Comment: I would like the tooltip to be displayed but also to have the action of opening the modal when I click

Comment: Yes it's hover and open the modal when I click

Comment: How can I do that in my case ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203556/discussion-between-thedevguy-and-seantunwin).

Comment: Thanks, Buddy! It is working as expected.